# CSS not updating on live but works for staging

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I seem to be having an issue with some CSS on our live platform.

We have an add to cart button which is pulling changes from 'index' rather than our css that we're pushing through.

This code seems to work fine on both our staging and live platforms:

```
.single-product div.product form.cart .quantity {
  float: initial;
}

.single-product div.product form.cart .button {
  float: initial;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 158px;
  background-color: #ff63b1;
 }
```

However, it seems that when we trying to change **.added_to_cart.alt, .button.alt, 
    button.alt, input[type=button].alt, input[type=reset].alt, 
    input[type=submit].alt {** it doesn't get recognised as if the code is incorrect and continues to pull from index.

This is the change we're trying to do which works fine on staging but not on live:

```
.added_to_cart.alt, .button.alt, button.alt, input[type=button].alt, 
input[type=reset].alt, input[type=submit].alt {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: Georgia;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  line-height: 20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 19px;
  padding-left: 158px;
  padding-right: 100px;
  color: #fff;
  border-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-style: none;
  border-color: #62b237;
  background-color: #47a332;
}
```

Our staging platform is a recent copy of our live (3 days ago) and no major changes have happened since our last copy. While checking inspect, it looks like the elements are the same and there isn't any errors in the console.

I've tried turning off our caching plugins on live and also removing my own browser history but this didn't work. I'm quite stuck now and could really do with some help.

If you want to check the code yourself, here is a link to our product page:
http://www.cutepinkboutique.com/product/selfish-love-heels/

Comment: which file you are using for css? style.css?

Comment: in which css file you did the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't link the CSS file correctly. This is what `it` looks like:

```
http://www.cutepinkboutique.com/?sccss=1&ver=4.7.5
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How does the CSS mentioned, not link correctly? What has caused the un-link?

Comment: Also the other recent css put in was input the same way and it uses that file fine.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I would expect the link to be like sc.css, including a dot. Or have a filename in front of the ? like /mycss.css?sccss=1&ver=4.7.5

Comment: Can you indicate where the CSS should be applied? I tried to locate the input elements without any luck.

Comment: Yes of course, its not an actual file but a plugin that I use called 'custom CSS' which I use to apply all of my CSS. This has worked with all of my CSS so far and does so on my staging.

Comment: It should be applied on the 'Add to bag' button, hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure why it is different in staging, but your CSS is overwritten by .single-product div.product form.cart .button {
    float: initial;
    margin-top: 30px;
    padding-right: 158px;
    background-color: #ff63b1;
}

Comment: Your correct. How very strange as I could not modify those attributes using that div. Thank you very much.